# Parsing different inputs in multi-part forms - React form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multipartform-data

I am currently getting errors in a form component I have built that I think are to do with the way the different types of inputs are set in my form. I have a method for setting the state of the form that I think is causing the problem for the file I am trying to submit.

```
const ArticleForm = (props) => {

    const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

    const fields = useSelector(state => state.fields);

    const { articleTypeList } = fields;

    // state for the current field value
    const [article, setArticle] = useState({
        articleTitle: ``,
        articleTypeID: ``,
        articleContent: ``,
        userID: ``,
        **photos: null,**
        error: ``,
    });

    // all onChange functions do the exact same thing, so you only need one
    // pass to a component like onChange={handleChange('typeID')}
    **const handleChange = (property) => (e) => {
        setArticle({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...article,
            [property]: e.target.value,
        });**
    }

    const handleChangeInt = (property) => (e) => {
        setArticle({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...article,
            [property]: parseInt(e.target.value),
        });
    }

    // get access to dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // useEffect with an empty dependency array is the same as componentDidMount
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(requireFieldData());
    }, []);

    function handleSubmitArticle(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("articleTitle", article.articleTitle);
        formData.append("articleContent", article.articleContent);
        formData.append("userID", article.userID);
        formData.append("articleTypeID", article.articleTypeID);
        formData.append("photos", article.photos);
        axios.post("http://localhost:5002/api/divelog/createdivelog", formData);
    }

    const classes = useStyles;

return (
    <div>

    <AppBar title="Enter your dive details"></AppBar>
    <form
        class="mt-4"
        id="articleForm"
        method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        onSubmit={handleSubmitArticle}>
        <>
            <Grid container spacing={3}
                  direction="row"
                  justify="center"
                  alignItems="center">
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                     <TextField
                      placeholder="Article-Title"
                      label="Article Title"
                      name="articleTitle"
                      margin="normal"
                      value={article.articleTitle}
                      onChange={handleChange("articleTitle")}
                      fullWidth/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={5}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder="Author-User-Number"
                            label="AuthorUserNumber"
                            // defaultValue={props.user.userID}
                            margin="normal"
                            value={props.user.userID}
                            onChange={handleChangeInt("userID")}
                            fullWidth/>
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={5}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                        <PopulateDropdown
                            dataList={articleTypeList}
                            titleProperty={"articleType"}
                            valueProperty={"articleTypeID"}
                            label="Article Type"
                            placeholder="Select article type"
                            value={article.articleTypeID}
                            onChange={handleChangeInt("articleTypeID")}/>
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                    <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.formControl}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder="Article Content"
                            label="ArticleContent"
                            name="articleContent"
                            value={article.articleContent}
                            onChange={handleChange("articleContent")}
                            multiline
                            rowsMax={6}
                            fullWidth/>
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <br />
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="photos">Photo Upload</label>
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            name="photos"
                            id="photos"
                            value={article.photos}
                            onChange={handleChange("photos")}/>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <br />
                <Grid item xs={8} md={6}>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Submit</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
    </>
    </form>
    </div>
)
}
```

I think this is the console error message relating to this error.

[image: ![enter image description here]

error message

```
(node:32864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at exports.createDiveLog (...roject\SustainableScuba\backend\controllers
\diveLog.controller.js:15:47)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...ess\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (...vproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\express\lib\rou
ter\route.js:137:13)
    at Array.<anonymous> (...roject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\mu
lter\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at listener (...ect\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\on-finished
\index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (...oject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\on-finished
\index.js:100:5)
    at callback (...evproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\ee-first\in
dex.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (...project\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modu
les\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(node:32864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside
of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:32864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at exports.createDiveLog (...oject\SustainableScuba\backend\controllers
\diveLog.controller.js:15:47)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...roject\SustainableScuba\backend\
node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField
  placeholder="Article-Title"
  label="Article Title"
  name="articleTitle"
  margin="normal"
  value={article.articleTitle}
  onChange={handleChange("articleTitle")}
  fullWidth/>
```

onChange should be wrong here, instead of returning new function, try to bind the property to the handle change function

the correct way of writing code is

```
onChange={handleChange.bind(null, "articleTitle")}
```

And your handleChange function will become like this

```
const handleChange = (property, e) => {
    setArticle({
        // override the changed property and keep the rest
        ...article,
        [property]: e.target.value,
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but now my submit button isn't active. My problem that I know of is that when the form is submitted the file is coming up as undefined. So it must be something to do with the useState method and setting the value.

Comment: The error is coming from the way the file / photos are being defined i believe. When a submit is clicked the backend throws an error message that the file is undefined.